# Should a flat steel door be painted with a brush or a roller?

Tags: painting

An outdoor flat steel door is to be painted:

[image]

Any suggestions and their reasons for the type of paint to be used is appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: with brush you will have stripes. with roller you will not.

Comment: With roller you will have stipple. Pick your poison, or up your skills.

Comment: Skip brush, roller and spray and head straight for Jackson Pollock drip-style territory. Why make a door boring?

Answer (score 3):

A brush or roller will get paint on it but? I would recommend although you did not mention it spray painting it. Your favorite box store will happily sell you a can or to of whatever color you want for not to many $$$. In the end a better finish and the clean up becomes easy.

Answer (score 3):

With brush, you will have stripes, and with rollers you will have stipple.  However this can be reduced.

Search "$99 Rust-oleum paint job". (think Rustoleum as found in gallon cans, not spray cans). The target is cars, but they display good techniques for doing "almost spray-like" finishes with **alkyd** paints from brush and roller.  Of course working with a flat door that is horizontal while painting will only make it easier still.

Working with latex/emulsion is more challenging but the concepts may help: ultra-thin the paint so gravity helps it lay flat, and plenty of coats.

I can get "spray-like" using that technique. However I cheat a bit, and use 2-part LPU marine paints which have special B-parts formulated to deliver "spray-like" finish with brush and roller.

Answer (score 1):

I never succeeded painting a perfectly flat surface with brush without seeing the stripes.

I blame it on paint, the brush, but never on my painting skills.

In that situation I prefer a roller. Actually a foam roller.